# How to plot beyond infinity with scaled axes in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting data using a custom axis transform that compresses the values from -Infinity to Infinity to fit within a finite range.  I would like to plot in positions that are beyond where Infinity is located on the axis.  Is there a clean way to do this?

Some ideas:

1. Transform the data instead of the axes and relabel the axes.
2. Change all Infinity values in the data to be a very large number, and then use even larger numbers to plot beyond infinity.

I don't like either of these because they change the data values.  It would be nice to have a way to directly access and plot on the non-transformed coordinates of the plot, but I can't find any way to do this.

Comment: Better to try the first approach.
How is it possible there is a space beyond +inf in the plot given your transform and how you define/know how much is it?
if possible post some code and plot.

Comment: this makes me want to quote Buzz Lightyear: "to infinity ... and beyond!"  (can we have a [mcve] please?)

Comment: The ability to plot on the non-transformed scale sounds an awful lot like having two positional scales, which is something that ggplot has historically very much frowned upon. So I would be very surprised to find a "sanctioned" way to do this. That said, you might be able to hack something together with `annotation_custom()`